# How to change the default Google Cloud username?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

I am new to Google Cloud Platform (GCP), I tried to create a new VM, but the default username is annoying. Say, my gmail is example.email@gmail.com, the username will be example_email.

How can I change it to something like: smith, instead of example_email?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

You cannot change the default username as it is based upon the Google Account identity.

You can use a different username by creating your own private/public keys and specifying the username along with the SSH public key (ssh-rsa) when you create the instance or by modifying the SSH settings on an existing instance.

[Adding or removing instance-level public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only)

Then you can log into the instance using SSH and your desired username (smith).

Comment: Hello John, thank you so much for your reply! I am wondering if I add a SSH key by this way for the user I created (smith), is it possible to make GCP's web SSH use this user?

Comment: Thank you! I am able to login in with smith with the generated key pair. But the VM still creates the default user example_email, and if I use the web SSH on GCP console, example_email is still logged in, is there a way to change it? I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser, I am now able to do what I was aiming to with your help and this article (for changing the default login user), thank you very much!